# AutoHotKey - Assign variable to key (shortcut)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I was wondering.. How can I assign a variable / text to a key (shortcut)?

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
myVar = Hello
 #F11 = myVar ;myVar ("hello") is stored / bound to the shortcut: `WINDOWS+F11`.
```

So, whenever I press `WINDOWS + F11`, it should paste/write the content of `myVar`.

Is this even possible? If yes, can I do it with multiply keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
SendMode Input

myVar := "Hello"
myOtherVar := "World"

#F10::Send, Hello world!
#F11::Send, %myVar%
#F12::Send, %myOtherVar%
```

You'll notice that the text is only sent when you release the WIN-key. This is intended, and is a special behavior for the WIN-modifier. You can read more about it [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols).